# TypeError: _this7._config.server.rewriteRequestUrl is not a function React native 0.64.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, react-native

I have followed all the instruction given at this [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.64.1) for upgrading RNv0.62 to v0.64.1 and my app is getting installed successfully in the device but my metro bundler is failing with some random error which I am unable to figure out at all.

Whenever I try to run my packager it throws this error `TypeError: _this7._config.server.rewriteRequestUrl is not a function at node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1011:39`
if anyone can help me what exactly should I do to debug this.

To understand the difference what I did that I logged `_this7._config.server` object in console for my project and a working 0.64.1 project,obviously both of them are different.

my `_this7._config.server` after update process

```
{
  useGlobalHotkey: true,
  port: 8081,
  enableVisualizer: false,
  enhanceMiddleware: [Function (anonymous)],
  runInspectorProxy: true,
  verifyConnections: false
}
```

other `_this7._config.server` for 0.64.1 which is working

```
{
  useGlobalHotkey: true,
  port: 8081,
  enhanceMiddleware: [Function (anonymous)],
  rewriteRequestUrl: [Function: rewriteRequestUrl],
  runInspectorProxy: true,
  verifyConnections: false
}
```

I am not able to figure out what exactly going wrong,due to both are different

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to bump up your metro version too.

I faces a similar issue and the issue was with metro version conflicts.

Our metro version was 0.56 and when migrating from 0.63 to 0.64 and *@react-native-community/cli* metro version gets bumped to 0.64.0.

Because of this metro resolution were failing and throwing this error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).